# First-order formula of rational numbers

Tags: set-theory

How to write in the pure language of set theory: "x is a rational number" (i.e., does there exist a formula lets call it rational(x) such that rational(x) that is true in V iff x is a rational number)? Is there some standard reference that you can recommend me?

Comment: Yes, there is. Are you familiar with the standard construction of rationals in set theory?

Comment: Such as $x\in\Bbb Q$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, but that Q is meta language. How would define in the language of set theory?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku I am! However, I have never found a definition of the rationals in the language of set theory such as Ord(x) for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to one common set of implementation choices:

- A set is *inductive* if it contains $\varnothing$ (which we denote by $0$) and is closed under the operation $S(x) = x\cup \{x\}$.
- A *natural number* is an element of the minimal inductive set $\mathbb{N}$.
- Use the recursion theorem to define $+$ to be the unique function $\mathbb{N}^2\to \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $m+0 = m$ and $m+S(n) = S(m+n)$.
- Use the recursion theorem to define $\times$ to be the unique function $\mathbb{N}^2\to \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $m\times 0 = 0$ and $m\times S(n) = (m\times n) + m$.
- An *integer* is an equivalence class of pairs of natural numbers under the equivalence relation $(a,b)\sim (c,d)$ iff $a+d = b+c$.
- The integer *zero* is the equivalence class containing $(n,n)$ for all natural numbers $n$.
- Define $\times'$ on integers by $[(a,b)]\times' [(c,d)] = [(a\times c+b\times d,a\times d + b\times c)]$.
- A *fraction* is a pair of integers $(p,q)$, where $q$ is not zero.
- A *rational number* is an equivalence class of fractions under the equivalence relation $(p,q)\approx (r,s)$ iff $p\times' s = q\times' r$.

All these definitions can be used to expand the definition of rational number to a formula in the language of set theory. Actually doing so would be quite tedious, so I don't recommend it. It's enough to convince yourself that it could be done in principle.

Answer (score 2):

One common approach is to view rationals as equivalence classes of elements of $\{0,1\}\times\omega\times(\omega\setminus \{0\})$, where intuitively the triple $(i,a,b)$ represents the number $(-1)^i\cdot{a\over b}$. Formally, the equivalence relation in question is given by $(i,a,b)\sim (i',a',b')$ iff

- $a=a'=0$, or
- $i=i'$ and $ab'=a'b$.

Note that this "leans on" the usual implementation of naturals as finite ordinals (and in particular on ordinal multiplication); at the same time, we do *not* literally have "$\mathbb{N}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$" (the natural number $3$, for example, corresponds to the equivalence class of $(0,3,1)$ which is a different object), and when we go on to construct the reals (e.g. via Dedekind cuts) we will analogously have a failure of "$\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$." C'est la vie.

Note that I said "one common approach" rather than "the standard approach." Like with the natural numbers, there are many different ways we could implement the rationals in set theory; unlike the naturals, however, it simply hasn't been important to fix one particular implementation as the default choice.